# How do I stop droppable event propagation with different parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

**To begin** greedy doesn't run when elements have different parents, and this element is superposed. Like this :

```
<div id="one">
  <div class="icone draggable"></div>
  <div id="background" class="droppable">
    <div id="grey" class="droppable"></div>
    <div id="red" class="droppable"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="two">
  <div id="yellow" class="droppable"></div>
</div>
```

If I drop *.icone* from *#red* to *#yellow* (*#yellow* is on *#background*), I have two events (drop event) like this :

```
start
drop in background (<= Bad event)
drop in yellow
```

But if I drop *.icone* from *#yellow* to *#red*, it works I have only **one** event :

```
start
drop in red
```

*#yellow* didn't stop event propagation, *#red* has a correct reaction.

And if I drag *.icone* in *#yellow*, I have three event instead one (in my orignal code I can set position of *.icone* when I drag it) :

```
start
drop in background (<= Bad event)
drop in yellow (<= Bad event)
drag in yellow
```

**See [my example code](http://jsbin.com/mubenaze/1/edit?js,console,output)**, How do I stop event propagation to *#yellow* ?

`#red` and `#yellow` can be superposed like this **[second example code](http://jsbin.com/pezokepa/1/edit)**.

I tried different solutions proposed on stackoverflow with over/out event who disable other droppable events. But if I use this solutions, I can't drop out *.icone* to *#yellow*.

Thank.

*(**See solution here :** http://jsbin.com/mubenaze/21/edit)*

Comment: so if i drag the green square from the yellow one to the blue background, it shouldn't accept it?

Comment: it should accept it, but if I drop green square from `red` to `yellow`, I must to have only one event (watch console.log).

Comment: so the extra "drop in background" shouldn't happen

Comment: but the point is that red has a "correct reaction" because in the html code yellow is not inside background. On the other hand when you're dropping something inside red you're releasing the green square both inside red and background.

Comment: nevermind my last comment ;) i got it

Comment: Can you catch `yellow` `drop-over` event, and if you can, try disable droppable for `background` div

Comment: I edited my post. Yes, the problem is that droppable element have different parent, but I can't change my HTML code.

Comment: RaraituL I can't disable droppable for background because if I disable it, I can't drop icone from red to background.

Comment: In the way i made it you can re-enable background when needed so that you can also work with red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are forced to work singularly on the exceptions like #yellow.
This is a possible solution but it might take some css fixes (since the disabled droppables get a opacity: 0.35;
But i can't think of any fix better than disabling the background when needed.

```
$( "#yellow" ).on( "dropout", function( event, ui ) {
$("#background").droppable('option', 'disabled', false);
} );

$( "#yellow" ).on( "dropover", function( event, ui ) {
$("#background").droppable('option', 'disabled', true);
} );
```

These options need to be added for each div which isn't inside the background.

REEDIT:
add this to reenable the #background after dropping:

```
$( "#yellow" ).on( "drop", function( event, ui ) {
$("#background").droppable('option', 'disabled', false);
} );
```

http://jsbin.com/mubenaze/18/

Comment: I want to keep my HTML code like this, I can't change HTML code.

Comment: oh so it's not a problem of not having access to the html file. you can't change it at all i see.

Comment: I don't talk to HTML code but the HTML structure (My original code is more complex that this example).

Comment: http://jsbin.com/mubenaze/21/ Perfect, tomorrow I try in my original code (I will click to set accept answer, if workly).

Comment: eheh yes the .not(this).droppable is a very good idea if there are a lot of divs to manage.

Comment: So? I guess this answer pointed you in the right direction. Aren't you going to accept it?